# Why no displacement seen in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, bump

With the node wrangler addon. I tried the node setup. Will the maps. With the cycles render i cannot see the bump result.

[image]

**Cycles Render Result**

[image]

**Node Setup**

[image]

In Material -> Setting i have selected Bump+Displacement but wired result.

[image]

Any suggestion or help whats going with the nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Displacement > Midlevel 0.6 > Scale 0.1 seems to be working fine.

[image]

I don't have the issue of missing bump in provided blend file.
Probably it is work of Denoiser? Pattern in that distance is really small.

Destruction on last image is caused by high Displacement Scale value.

Comment: in closeup view it is visible. in distance view its just a plane color. how can i adjust

Comment: Disable denoiser ... Or scale up texture ... ?